# how to solve the error gradle execution failed error?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

- Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.*

> above typed is my actual error

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xeoscript.eduapp.ca.application"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.2'
}
```

please help me fast

Comment: Well, have you looked into the compiler output for errors?

Comment: Yup, probably something that won't compile in your application (Java) code.